# The setBounds method created a black rectange on the PDF annotation on MacOS 10.13

Tags: objective-c, macos, pdf-annotations, macos-high-sierra

I have made a PDF Annotation program but when I test it on the Mac OS High Sierra 10.13, I found that all annotations could not be displayed well. Finally I found out it is this code:

```
[pdfannotation setBounds: bound];
```

Once I delete this code, the black rectangle would not appear anymore but the annotation would not show either..

Please help...

Comment: I have also reported this bug to Apple just now. I tested the code and it worked well on Mac OS Sierra 10.12

Comment: I updated the Xcode and it finally worked... How can I close this question?

Comment: is highlight annotation working fine for you ? I am unable to delete it.

Comment: it still has problems. I have also tested the Preview program, it shows black rectangles too. Mac OS 10.13 seed 6...